# How to check presence of a certain value in inner array and fetch some other value from the same inner array in following scenario?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, associative-array, key-value

I've following associative array titled `$requests`:

Note : Following is the output of the statement `print_r($requests);`

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [request_id] => 33
            [is_seen] => 1
            [message] => 
            [friend_user_id] => 901
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [request_id] => 23
            [is_seen] => 1
            [message] => 
            [friend_user_id] => 970
        )

)
```

Now what I want to achieve is I'll take value from user in a variable say `$friend_user_id`. Now I've to parse through the above array for checking whether any of the inner array has got the same value as of `$friend_user_id` in a key titled `['friend_user_id']`. If the match is found then the value from key `['request_id']` from the same inner array should be fetched, if no match is found then it should return nothing.

For example, the variable `$friend_user_id` contains value **901** then it should return me **33**(the respective request_id)

How should I achieve this in an efficient, optimum and reliable way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post your attempts too to identify at which optimum level you want to be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple `foreach` along with `in_array` will do the trick as

```
$friend_user_id = 901;
foreach($arr as $key => $value){
    if(in_array($friend_user_id,$value)){
        $request_id = $value['request_id'];
    }
}
echo $request_id;
```

[<kbd>**Fiddle**</kbd>](https://eval.in/408748)

Comment: First of all thank you so much for your help. Just small request from me. I'm getting the result as Array
(
    [request_id] => Array
        (
            [0] => 33
        )

)
But I want the result in following manner only 
$request_id = 33;
That's it. Can you please make the necessary change to your answer and update it, so that I can accept your answer? Thanks once again.